# c# new Thread(() to Application.Current.Dispatcher taking long time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio

I created the new thread inside main thread

```
     new Thread(() =>
                    {
                       // my code
                       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("my code completed");
                       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(MyMethod, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
                    }).Start();
```

After executing the `my code` it take 5-8 seconds to call the `MyMethod`

I saw in the output window that, given bellow line occurs few times before calling the `MyMethod`

```
The thread 0x2954 has exited with code 259 (0x103)
```

To fix this, I tired to Abort the current thread using  `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();` but its not solving my problem. I want to call `MyMethod` immediately after `my code` completed.

Comment: Instead of using Threads why not use Tasks and then you can call MyMethod using Task.ContinueWith. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Threads to find out why the main thread is so busy, watch out for it burning 100% core.  Using Invoke instead of BeginInvoke is a standard WPF mistake.  The 259 exit code is caused by a bug in VS2015 and doesn't otherwise mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a thread, a lot of processing takes place before your code actually runs.  If you need your code to be more responsive, take a look at thread pools (`Task` are basically the same thing).

Bear in mind that even with a thread pool it can take a little while to start things off, but it should be much less than starting with a brand new thread.

With your code, what you are doing is starting a thread (which might take a long time), then asking your thread to pass control back to the UI thread, which itself might be busy doing other things and not able to run your code until it is free.

Comment: Also bear in mind, even with a thread pool, all the threads in the pool may be busy thus putting your new thread on hold until one frees up.

Comment: "Task are basically the same thing". No, a `Task` does not involve a `Thread`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Tasks are ultimately run on threads, but the difference is subtle to a beginner like Vijay.  To an expert such as yourself, that difference might be enormous.